# Portable Python/IPython

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently starting a business where I will be providing support to clients directly on their business offices. I need to be able to go to different computers and be able to run custom python scripts, my question is if there's a way to make my python environment portable?

Comment: You could just install a virtual Python environment on a thumb drive, then have your scripts loaded on that drive and use that environment.

Comment: by any chance do you have instructions on how to go about it?

Comment: [This](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) is the standard documentation for the built-in method.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your users are running Windows, I see two options here.

1. If you have already defined which scripts you will be running, compile them into exe files using [py2exe](https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/), that way you can just plug a USB and run them as needed. (the caveat is that some antivirus will automatically block the unsigned executables)
2. The other option is to use [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/), that is a full python environment with a lot of packages already preinstalled that ives in it's own directory. In case you need to install a new package, just use the Powershell or CMD that comes with it and use the preinstalled "pip".

Comment: I have already considered option #1 but I need to be able to modify scripts on the spot. I will give option #2 a try. Thanks!

Comment: Carcigenicate's options sounds pretty good too 

Note that WinPython has a built in Jupyter Lab, which will satisfy the Ipython need too.

If you find my answer useful, kindly accept it and upvote please.

Answer (score 1):

I found something interesting here [Portable Python](https://mypclab.com/create-a-portable-python-3-10-virtual-environment/). I use that method to create portable Python 3.9 and 3.10 and everything works so have a look.

Answer (score 0):

conda-pack would be a solution - https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/.

> conda-pack is a command line tool for creating archives of conda environments that can be installed on other systems and locations. This is useful for deploying code in a consistent environment—potentially where python and/or conda isn’t already installed.

It will not only package the dependencies, but also won't rely on presence of python on target machine. Conda-unpack is quite fast and you will only need to run it when your environment changes, not when your scripts do.